# Generating random matrices in C

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to generate two different 5x5 matrices between -25 and 25. I can easily generate 1 matrices but every time I try to generate the second one, the program crashes. I am required to use a function to generate this two matrices.

```
generate_matrices(int p[5][5],int q[5][5])
```

If I remove the **int q[5][5]**, it works fine but crashes when included.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a [5][5], b[5][5];
    generate_matrices(a[5][5], b[5][5]);
    return 0;
}

void generate_matrices(int p[5][5], int q[5][5])
{
   int i=0,seed, r, row=0, column=0, s;
   printf("Enter a number:");
   scanf("%d",&seed);
   srand(seed);

   for (row=0; row < 5; row++ )
   {
      for (column=0; column < 5; column++ )
      {
        r = rand() % 50 + (-25); // generates random number
        s = rand() % 50 + (-25); // generates random number
        printf("p[%d][%d]:%d\t", row, column,p[row][column]=r);
        printf("q[%d][%d]:%d\t", row, column,q[row][column]=s);// if i comment this one it works fine and generate only p[5][5]
        i++;
        if (column ==4)
            {
                printf("\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this an hardware issue or has to do with my code.

Comment: C != C++, and you should generally only tag the one you are writing/compiling.

Comment: try calling just `generate_matrices(a,b);` -- also, not sure why you are doing an assignment inside your `printf` but I do c++ not C and you have tagged this question with both languages

Comment: Actually compiler warns about incorrect call of `generate_matrices`, I wonder why people don't read compiler warnings. And if the source is compiled as C++, not C, the warning becomes the error.

Comment: @Paul If I change the type of `generate_matrices` from `void` to `int`, the warning goes away but still no difference. It still crashes.

Comment: You should get a " missing declaration/prototype" or simliar warning for the call of `generate_matrices`.

Comment: @fredjames that's not what Paul was referring to. he's talking about how you _call_ the function

Comment: @fredjames You should get warning `matrices.c:8:23: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'int (*)[5]' [-Wint-conversion]` or something similar. When you call the function as `generate_matrices(a[5][5], b[5][5])` you don't pass matrices to the function. You pass elements of the matrices, which are out of bounds. This is because you have 5 rows and 5 columns and you are accessing 6th element of 6th row.

Comment: @Paul I didn't get that type of warning, the warning I got was not declaring (which was my mistake). I declared it now before `main()` and changed `generate_matrices(a[5][5], b[5][5]);` to  `generate_matrices(a, b);` and it worked.

Comment: It's off topic, but if you want values in the range between -25 and +25 (with both extremes included) you should use `r = rand() % 51 - 25;`.

Comment: @fredjames Maybe your compiler is too old or you have this warning muted somehow, I don't know. By the way, clang produces another warning: `matrices.c:8:23: warning: array index 5 is past the end of the array (which contains 5 elements) [-Warray-bounds]` which actually tells you about the reason of the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following changes help?
Before `main()`, declare the function

```
void generate_matrices(int[5][5], int[5][5]);
```

Pass the two matrices as below:

```
generate_matrices(a, b);
```